# can I switch IE10 debug bar to an iframe? Like cd(frames[0]) in Firebug. Is there any similar command?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, javascript-debugger

I need to debug JavaScript in IE10. When I place "debugger" keyword in the script source code it doesn't stop. So I decided to set debug point in the debug panel itself. But todo that I need to find the file with source code, which is loaded to iframe. So I need to switch to that frame somehow. :) When I say "switch" I mean get the iframe's context not main window's context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your iframe content is loaded, you can select any included script file from the drop down box located right under the toolbar, close to the vertical splitter.

I have placed a red frame around it on the picture.

When your script is loaded into the left panel, you can debug it with the usual tools: breakpoints, <kbd>F10</kbd> / <kbd>F11</kbd> etc.

See [image]